# ValueError: Output of generator should be a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` or `(x, y)`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm new to Keras and I'm trying to train a face detection machine in Python. As you can see the generator returned values but it seems that the output is not in suitable format. Any advice is highly appreciated

The full ValueError is as following:

> ValueError: Output of generator should be a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` 
>     or `(x, y)`. Found: [[[[0.10196079 0.08235294 0.07058824]
>    [0.10196079 0.08235294 0.07058824]
>     [0.10196079 0.08235294 0.07058824]
>     ...
>     [0.10196079 0.08235294 0.07058824]
>     [0.10196079 0.08235294 0.07058824]
>     [0.10196079 0.08235294 0.07058824]]

Here is the traceback

> File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled4/transferLearning.py", line > 103, in  callbacks=[checkpoint, early])
>     File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site->packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
>      return func(*args, **kwargs)
>    File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
>       initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
>   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site->packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 198, in fit_generator
>      str(generator_output))

Full code below

```
image_dir = path.join(root_dir, 'train_countinghead', 'image_data')

img_width, img_height = 256, 256
train_csv = pandas.read_csv(path.join(root_dir, 'train_countinghead', 'train.csv'))
test_csv = pandas.read_csv(path.join(root_dir, 'test_headcount.csv'))

train_samples = len(train_csv)
test_samples = len(test_csv)
batch_size = 16
epochs = 50

model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))

# Freeze the layers which you don't want to train. Here I am freezing the first 5 layers.
for layer in model.layers[:5]:
    layer.trainable = False

# Adding custom Layers
x = model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
predictions = Dense(16, activation="softmax")(x)

# creating the final model
model_final = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=predictions)

# compile the model
model_final.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9),
                    metrics=["accuracy"])

# Initiate the train and test generators with data Augumentation
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest",
    zoom_range=0.3,
    width_shift_range=0.3,
    height_shift_range=0.3,
    rotation_range=30
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest",
    zoom_range=0.3,
    width_shift_range=0.3,
    height_shift_range=0.3,
    rotation_range=30
)

# if `class_mode` is `"categorical"` (default value) it must include the `y_col` column with the class/es of each image.
# Check the comments in method definition for more

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=train_csv,
    directory=image_dir,
    x_col='Name',
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode=None
)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=test_csv,
    directory=image_dir,
    x_col='Name',
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode=None
)

# Save the model according to the conditions
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(path.join(root_dir, "vgg16_1.h5"), monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                             save_weights_only=False,
                             mode='auto', period=1)
early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0, patience=10, verbose=1, mode='auto')

# Train the model
model_final.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    # samples_per_epoch=train_samples,
    steps_per_epoch=train_samples / batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=test_generator,
    validation_steps=test_samples / batch_size,
    callbacks=[checkpoint, early])
```

Comment: Hey @Zhen Hao, don't forget to [upvote my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that here you didn't provide a target column.
If you look at [the documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_dataframe), you can see that you need (because you are training your model) to specify a `y_col` and also not have `class_mode=None` (which is only used for prediction), at least for the `train_generator` (I don't know what you plan to do with the `test_generator`).

You could also have seen that using the error, which was telling you that it wasn't getting all the necessary elements (`x` the data, `y` the label).

Comment: But the problem is my csv contains only 2 columns, filename and the number of head counts (I'm training a face detection machine). If I change it to class_mode = 'categorical'. I get another error which is TypeError: If class_mode="categorical", y_col="HeadCount" column values must be type string, list or tuple.

Comment: Or should I use another class_mode? Sorry I'm total beginner in ML

Comment: Well if your target value is the head count in the image, then you should use `"sparse"` most likely (but you could do `"other"`). You can read in the documentation the different types of `class_mode` you have.